# Is HTML allowed in objects description?

Tags: html, object, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to use HTML tags in objects description, like links? I am trying to post a link on the wall with my app but it skips HTML stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your question - no. You can't use HTML tags at all when posting data to Facebook.